# linear-gradient on 2-pieced background

Tags: css, background-image, linear-gradients, border-image

I'm making a client's website that has the following design in it:

[image: design]

As you can see, the 3 block have a variable content size, but the top is the same. It also has a subtle gradient that runs over the whole shape.

To accomplish the design, I made a parent `div`, with 2 child divs: `.background` & `.content`, which overlap each other (`position` + `z-index`).

Inside `.background`, I have 2 `div`'s: `.triangle` & `.block`.
Since `.triangle` has a fixed height (`220px`), the gradient for `.block` can start at `-220px`: `linear-gradient(yellow -220px, green 100%)`.
But the problem is that my `.block` div has a variable height, so I don't know where to end the `.triangle`'s gradient.

Also if I use a `border-image` on `.triangle`, my triangle shape gets lost. I'd like to do it in CSS only if that's possible.

I've put a little JSFiddle together to make my problem more clear: https://jsfiddle.net/c1pgeq7j

Comment: Hello, why don't you start your linear-gradient at 0 ? `background-image: linear-gradient(blue 0, green 100%);`. It's not perfect because your triangle is plain blue, but depending of the height of the block, it looks more than ok, don't you think ?

Comment: you can try some thing like this .... https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/c1pgeq7j/1/

Comment: @Kangouroops I can start my `linear-gradient` at 0 on `.triangle`, but on `.block`, the gradient is already happening, so I have to start at `-220px` (the height of `.triangle`)

Comment: @ChandraShekhar That looks like something I could use  Can you explain it a bit more how it works please? How did you get the triangle shape without an extra `div`?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Your solution isn't working unfortunattely  If the text inside content block gets bigger, the angle isn't like the design anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/c1pgeq7j/5

Comment: Not too sure about which is your issue , so its going to be a comment. gradient start/stop color can be tuned any time. Is it about overlapping bg  ? , alignement (flex) ?  where would this be about :  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PKGxMO

Comment: @GCyrillus It's about the `linear-gradient` that starts at the top of `.triangle` and ends at the bottom of `.block`

Comment: okay, is there a reason why you do not use a linear-gradient (or png ) in the background of a single container ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Not really, It's just that the `.triangle` is always `220px` high and `.block` has a variable height. And the `border`-trick is the only useful one I found for making triangles with CSS only

Comment: i see , nothing responsise is needed then, columns won't shrink nor fall , you only need to apply the same rgba color to the border(triangle) and to the bg (block) ?

Comment: @GCyrillus If it would be 1 color it should indeed, but it's a `linear-gradient`, which starts at the top of `.triangle` and ends at the bottom of `.block`. So for `.block` I can let the gradient start at `-220px` (the **fixed** height of `.triangle`), but since `.block` has a variable `height`, I don't know where to end the `linear-gradient` of `.triangle`. 

Comment: @MichaelDeBoey Did you check my example ? the linear gradient has 2 colors + transparent,  the 220px can be respected for the print, but on screens of any size and shapes , an average size or a ratio might be better to care about to keep the spirit of the design. the example has an average height of 150px but it can be tuned to more or less (degrees, start/stop values, and  padding to keep content down here is the link again https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/PKGxMO , you can fork it and play with the gradients values and padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Adam Wathan for [giving me the answer](https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/893093689396011008) I was looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/c1pgeq7j/10

He ended up with no child-`div`s in `.background` and applying the following CSS to it:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#176EFD, #1152B7);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 220px);
```

Only need to add the `-webkit-`variant of `clip-path`, so it's also supported in the newest version of `Safari`.

Thanks for trying to help me out people!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-container">
      <section>
       <h1>Content</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent et est urna. Pellentesque hendrerit lobortis tincidunt. Sed et malesuada ante. Donec sit amet molestie libero. Nam sed gravida nunc. Ut porttitor rhoncus volutpat. Quisque eu sollicitudin quam. Quisque tempor justo eget sodales maximus.

Ut pharetra nulla sit amet augue vulputate pharetra. Nulla facilisis turpis vel velit commodo, eget feugiat leo tincidunt. Aenean consequat sapien vitae porttitor euismod. Quisque dictum vitae erat ac commodo. Nunc cursus a dolor et rutrum. Nunc lobortis a urna eu auctor. Curabitur cursus diam non lect</p>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  padding-top: 97px;
}

.main-container {
  background: #00b7ea;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 49%, #009ec3 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 49%,#009ec3 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00b7ea 49%,#009ec3 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 );
  position: relative;
  height: 220px;
}

.main-container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -53px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  background: #00b7ea;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(8.5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(8.5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(8.5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(8.5deg);
  transform: skewY(8.5deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

section {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c1pgeq7j/4/

try to play with `transform: skewY(8.5deg);` for the other side of slanting and for the gradient try to check [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: The problem here is that the `linear-gradient` only starts at 49%.
It should start at `-220px` (the top of the triangle).
https://jsfiddle.net/c1pgeq7j/7